PHP CURL would not retrieve table content
I am trying to scrawl table content from a webpage from canada.ca. It seems that the retrieved content is missing certain parts, as described in the following code:
<?php
$url="https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/mandate/policies-operational-instructions-agreements/ministerial-instructions/express-entry-rounds.html";
$base = $url;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36');

$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $str; // from what shown, we can decide table header ("#   Date    Round type  ...") exists, but other table rows are missing

It seems that "tr" inside "table/tbody" are lost. It must be something in the CURL parameters. What could it be?

It's not the CURL parameters. Look at the page source code (In Chrome, you can do this by prepending "view-source:" to the URL, or using Ctrl+U). The information you're crawling is mostly populated with Javascript. It uses the JSON response from this endpoint to fill in all of its rows.

Could you please specify if you are seeking to retrieve data from this specific page, or if you are interested in learning how to parse a table from a web page using PHP? If your intention is to fetch data solely from this page, you might consider using the endpoint mentioned by maiorano84 or @Bartje06.

You can use the .json url for importing the data:
https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/documents/json/ee_rounds_123_en.json
You can try this php code:
<?php
// The URL of the JSON file
$json_url = 'https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/documents/json/ee_rounds_123_en.json';

// Fetch the JSON data using file_get_contents
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);

// Check if the fetch was successful
if ($json_data === false) {
    die('Error fetching JSON data');
}

// Decode the JSON data
$decoded_data = json_decode($json_data, true);

// Check if decoding was successful
if ($decoded_data === null) {
    die('Error decoding JSON data');
}

// Use the decoded data
print_r($decoded_data);
?>

